# Grammatical correctness of the following sentence if and would

Tags: conditional-constructions

This is the sentence I am trying to understand grammatically

> In fact, if you want to go on a diet, one of the first things a dietician in Sri Lanka would tell you is to moderate the use of coconut milk in your dishes!

based on my understanding, I could use "would" if it is a second conditional sentence. which means,

"If you wanted to go on diet, they would tell you"

Could someone help me clear my doubts about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a subjunctive used in relation to a conditional.

> If you want to go on a diet...

That sets up the condition, albeit with minimal detail and you have to construct that from other phrases/clauses.

> a dietitian ... would tell you...

Is the hypothetical (hence subjunctive) event that one expects to occur in relation to that condition.

*In fact* is just sugar, really, set up to indicate this sentence's relationship with prior text. The modifying effect of *one of the first things* is hopefully clear, as is that of *in Sri Lanka*.

The overall effect is to state that, should one tell a dietitian in Sri Lanka that one wanted to go on a diet, the expected result is that they will tell you to moderate the use of coconut milk.

*However*, it's a little different to the most natural way I would express it. It uses *want* rather than *wanted*, and if this were a purely hypothetical situation I would expect the latter. The effect, to me, of using the simple present in the conditional is to create a greater sense of dialogue between the text and the reader; *you* used in the specific rather than the general sense. It thus feels like it is actually talking about the possibility that the reader does, right now, want to go on a diet.